# How to use the phrase "refer to"

Tags: meaning

I just know it has the meaning of mentioning something, talking about something, being related to something,etc.

Comment: Hi Lin, welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately your question makes no sense. Please [edit] it to make it clearer what you mean, and also explain what research you've done. Why do you think there's some kind of limit? What is it the limit of? You may find our other site [ell.se] more appropriate for this kind of question. :-)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. Actually, my question is what the meaning of 'refer to' is and how i can use properly in dialogue.

Comment: Hi Lin. Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial attempts at research; for example, did you look the phrase up in a dictionary? If so, what did you find, and why doesn't it answer your question? I strongly encourage you to take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be of interest if you are learning English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically ***refer to*** means:

> to look at or in (something) for information

or

> to talk about or write about (someone or something) especially briefly
>   : to mention (someone or something) in speech or in writing

Link: [refer to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refer%20to)

Finally, you can find a few examples of how it can be used here: [How to use refer to in a sentence](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/refer_to.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I got the point.